# Кастомизация AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, dropdown, autocompletetextview

Сменил стандартный `simple_list_item_1` на свой `xml` с `TextView`, в котором получилось настроить только цвет фона. Помимо это мне всего то нужно, чтоб ширина выпадающего списка подстраивалась под длинный текст, ну или хотя бы чтоб я мог её вручную установить. Это я пытался сделать через `android:dropDownWidth`, но что бы я туда ни писал, список не становится шире, чем поле для ввода, которое у меня не во весь экран размером. Ну и во-вторых, у меня какого-то лешего нету разделителей между строками, ни в `simple_list_item_1`, ни в собственном `xml`. Пытался сделать через `android:divider`,  что тоже, естественно, не сработало.

Это вот мой `activity.java` файл:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AutoCompleteTextView tv;
String[] list={"длинный текст, который должен поместиться!", "и ещё", "какие-нибудь", "элементы"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.listxml,list);

    tv.setAdapter(adapter);
    tv.setThreshold(1);
}
}
```

А это вот `listxml.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/some_value"
    android:id="@+id/listxml"
    android:background="@color/some_color"
    android:divider="@color/some_color2"/>
```

Comment: i am so lame, Вот [туториал](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/), надеюсь поможет!

Comment: @Omuradil , не нашёл ничего по сабжу. Если рассматривать как альтернативный метод для реализации моей задачи, то он, к сожалению, мне не подходит. Я с самого начала пользовал ListView, фильтрующийся через EditText. Выглядело это как надо: можно было подогнать под нужный размер, были разделители. Но получившийся код был слишком сложный и некрасивый, и иного решения, кроме как использовать другой виджет, не нашлось. Больше о моей проблеме: http://tinyurl.com/zpv6he6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

параметры нужно указывать для виджета `AutoCompleteTextView`, а не для разметки айтема

Например, так может выглядеть разметка `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

здесь указано:
 `android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"` - отводить максимальное место - до границы родительского контейнера. Так же вы можете задать фиксированное значение.
`android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="50dp"` - смещение выпадающего списка от начала виджета на *50dp* вправо.

C разделителями сложнее, здесь используется  `ListPopupWindow`, для него не предусмотрено готового механизма назначить дивидер. Решение в лоб - можно просто назначить для `TextView` из айтема бэкграунд с полоской внизу. Недостаток - последний элемент тоже будет с дивидером.

Comment: Хвала вам, батюшка! И как же я сам то не допёр. Ну ламир, чёж с меня взять( 
Но как с разделителями быть? До этого я точно не допру.

Comment: Хотя постойте, сейчас вроде допру!  :D Если не допру, то напишу.

Comment: ну что ж, спасибо большое! Поставил бэкграунд, так даже лучше выглядит!